# Toolbar item (Notification bell with Count overlay) not responding to click

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have notification bell icon at toolbar with notification count text. It works as expected but when notification count is zero then click on bell icon not working. I think it's because of action layout which shows count over notification bell but at the same time i think bell icon should take onclick events. I know it's something i miss but i am able to figure out where the code break. Please help me out.

Menuitem

```
   <item android:id="@+id/notificationBell"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menuitem_notification_count"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
```

Action Layout - menuitem_notification_count

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/notification"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_count_background"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_notification, menu);
        MenuItem notificationBell = menu.findItem(R.id.notificationBell);
        textNotificationCount = notificationBell.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
        Typeface fontFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getActivity(), R.font.roboto_medium_numbers);
        textNotificationCount.setTypeface(fontFace);
        notificationCount = getNotificationCount();
        int checkCount = Integer.parseInt(notificationCount);
        Log.d(TAG, "run:  Notification Count = " + notificationCount);
        notificationBell.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (checkCount==0){
                    // THIS TOAST AND LOG NEVER SHOWS 
                    Log.d(TAG, "run:  Notification Count Is 0");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No New Notifications.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        if (checkCount == 0) {
            if (textNotificationCount.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                textNotificationCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if (checkCount > 99) {
            //textNotificationCount.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(notificationCount, 99))+"+");
            textNotificationCount.setText("99+");
            if (textNotificationCount.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                textNotificationCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            textNotificationCount.setText(notificationCount);
            if (textNotificationCount.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                textNotificationCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        textNotificationCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // ON CLICK WORKS WHEN COUNT IS NOT ZERO
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Just add your own `Toolbar` to each layout. Trying to work around the built-in one in such a needless pain.

Comment: @GavinWright I am using Toolbar but i feel its an issue of action layout

Comment: Which app theme are you using? I'm suggesting that you use one like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, and then add the `Toolbar` into your layout manually.

Comment: you are correct the issues comes in your action layout. You are using bell icon in menuitem and also in action layout. So leave menuitem and go with action layout's `Imageview`  on click listener

Comment: @androidXP can you please show me the code. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting through the same problem for a while with a `MaterialToolbar`.

According to [this post on copyprogramming.com](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/onoptionsitemselected-not-called#onoptionsitemselected-not-called-when-using-actionlayout-sherlockactionbar), there is a known issue with some toolbar implementations.

A solution that worked for me was to set the OnClickListener manually on the layout view:

```kotlin
val toolbar = view.findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.the_toolbar)
val actionView = toolbar.menu
    .findItem(R.id.notifications_menu_item).actionView
actionView!!.setOnClickListener { view ->
    // Do something
}
```